# SQL Server 2008 Query with Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following Table in my SQL Server 2008 database

```
dbo.FormEmployment
------------------
employmentID int (PK)
formID int (FK)
gradeID int
employerName nvarchar
```

I wish to create a query that will select all Users based on their gradeID. At the moment I have the following query

```
DECLARE @gradeID int
SET @gradeID = 1

SELECT distinct u.userID, u.userTypeID, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.password, u.contactNumber, u.organisationID, u.emailVerificationCode, u.mobileVerificationCode, u.userStatusID 

FROM [User] u, dbo.FormEmployment emp, dbo.Form f

WHERE u.userTypeID = 47 
--Grades
AND emp.gradeID = @gradeID
AND f.formID = emp.formID
AND f.locumID = u.userID
```

The above query allows me to state a single gradeID and then get all Users who match that gradeID. However, I also need to be able to state several gradeIDs, for example, 
I would like for my parameter, @gradeID, to be like this

SET @gradeID = 1, 2, 3

So that it would get all the Users who have grades 1, 2 or 3.

Is there anyway of doing this? Any help or guidance with this would be greatly appreciated as the search I have to build for an application relies on it.

Thanks.

**Edit**

More information about how the search will work.

Each GradeID will be stored in a table within the database. The User will see a checkboxlist of the gradeIDs, and they will then be able to select as many gradeIDs from this list as they wish. Once they click 'submit', the gradeIDs they have selected will be passed to my stored procedure to perform the search.

Comment: Would @gradeID always be a contiguous range of numbers?

Comment: CatchingMonkey - Yes, gradeID will always be of type integer, eg, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...and so on

Comment: if users can check whatever grades they want, the resulting list won't be a continuous range from 1 to 7 or whatever, but a discrete list, e.g. [1,2,10,15,20,100]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @grades
        TABLE
        (
        id INT
        )

INSERT
INTO    @grades
VALUES
        (1),
        (2),
        (3)

SELECT   u.userID, u.userTypeID, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, u.password, u.contactNumber, u.organisationID, u.emailVerificationCode, u.mobileVerificationCode, u.userStatusID 
FROM     [User] u
WHERE    userId IN
         (
         SELECT  f.locumId
         FROM    FormEmployment emp
         JOIN    Form f
         ON      f.formId = emp.formId
         WHERE   emp.gradeId IN
                 (
                 SELECT  id
                 FROM    @grades
                 )
         )
         AND u.userTypeID = 47
```

Comment: Quassnoi - Instead of hardcoding the grades (1,2,3) to insert into the grades Table, how could I populate the grades Table with integers from another table, ie, by doing a select? Like this INSERT INTO @grades VALUES(select gradeID from dbo.ShiftGrade where shiftID = 10)

Comment: @tgriffiths: this would work too. In `ASP.NET` you can pass a table variable as a parameter to a query (or a stored procedure). But why don't you just put `select gradeID from dbo.ShiftGrade where shiftID = 10` into the `IN` clause?

Comment: Quassnoi - I put the 'select gradeID from dbo.ShiftGrade where shiftID = 10' into the 'IN' clause and it worked good, thanks. However, I also tried the option of putting it in like this 'INSERT INTO @grades VALUES(select gradeID from dbo.ShiftGrade where shiftID = 10)' however this does not seem to work? It gives me an error saying 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'. Is there a way of fixing this? **Thanks**.

Comment: @tgriffiths: `INSERT INTO @grades SELECT gradeId FROM shiftGrade WHERE shiftId = 10`

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity :

```
SELECT (...) 
FROM (...) 
WHERE emp.gradeID IN (@gradeID1, @gradeID2, @gradeID3)
```

If the number of parameters is not know, you can generate the sql IN clause at runtime (and at the same time add the parameters to the `SqlCommand` instance)

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem with this solution is that there could be as many 100 gradeIDs, therefore, it would mean writing IN (@gradeID1....@gradeID100)...which is something I'd prefer not to do

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need. Are the gradeID know in advance ? If not, where are they defined (in a database table, or given by the application?). In your question you say you want to use the sql query in a application but without giving any information about platform or framework.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know the sql statement was in a stored procedure. That's a totally different question.

Comment: What difference does it make? The query syntax should be very similar.